# How to reduce size of /vendor directory in a Silex project

Tags: symfony, composer-php, silex

I created a frontend API for an existing tourism booking system. In order to distribute it, I want to reduce the size of my /vendor directory. It has a total size of 26.4 MB.

Those are the biggest directories in /vendor (size in KB):

```
14402   ./symfony
4611    ./swiftmailer
3501    ./doctrine
2032    ./twig
844     ./monolog
826     ./silex
105     ./composer
56      ./pimple
39      ./psr
```

This is my composer.json file: http://pastebin.com/mBi5V0PH. I already removed unnecessary libraries, but the biggest chunk are ./swiftmailer and ./symfony and add to over 20MB.

How can I reduce the size to a total of around 10MB?

Comment: Typically you would distribute your library without the `vendor` directory and run `composer install` after it is in place. What is your distribution procedure?

Comment: Provide the Silex app as a zip directory to the customer. It will be unzipped, the config files can be adapted and than uploaded to the webserver. This all must be possible with basic webmaster knowledge and without SSH access.

Comment: @justinhoward I have a feeling that this is an application, not a library.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is not really a way to optimize included libraries for distribution. The only optimization I would suggest is to separate your development dependencies. Assuming you're using `symfony/browser-kit` and `symfony/css-selector` for testing, you could put those into the `require-dev` section in your `composer.json`.

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/dbal": ">=2.2.0,<2.4.0-dev",
        "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0.0",
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "silex/silex": "~1.2",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.*",
        "symfony/config": "~2.3",
        "symfony/console": "~2.3",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.3",
        "symfony/form": "~2.3",
        "symfony/locale": "~2.3",
        "symfony/translation": "~2.3",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.3",
        "symfony/yaml": "~2.3",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
        "twig/extensions": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "~2.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~2.3"
    }
}
```

Then before you zip up your distribution, run composer with

```bash
composer install --no-dev
```

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable procedure. Will try and post results.

Comment: You could also delete any tests and documentation from vendor ( see: [composer cleanup plugin](https://github.com/barryvdh/composer-cleanup-plugin) ) and run composer install with `--prefer-dist` option, which will make Composer prefer zip archives instead of git clone. This will free some space used by git history.